# Multiple Axios GET requests from different components

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I have 2 different components that render in main screen. Both have multiple axios.get requests to fill some data. But at first page load only the last component returns data and the first one is waiting for like 60 seconds to fill it's data. I don't know if it's React issue or my express server issue so here is the sample codes

**Main.JS**

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ComponentA />
        <ComponentB />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**ComponentA.JS**

```
 async componentDidMount() {
        const live = await axios.get('api link');
        const current = await axios.get('api link');
        this.setState({
            some states
        })
    }
```

**ComponentB.JS**

```
async componentDidMount() {
        const live = await axios.get('api link');
        this.setState({
            some states
        })
    }
```

express.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var sql = require('mssql');

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin,Content-Type, Authorization, x-id, Content-Length, X-Requested-With");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    next();
});

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port
});

app.get('/api', function (req, res) {
    res.end(some values)
})
```

Comment: Its time taken to fetch data from the Server, You are doing some costlier operation on your API in your first component?

Comment: no it just returns 4 digits numbers. If i call them alone i can fetch data. That's why i'm not sure if my express server can handle multiple requests or not

Comment: Test your API in Postman ? If its not working right post your code here

Comment: @ggnoredo Instead of making your lifecycle method async you need to make API(axios) call async.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd just chain axios calls with .then()

```
    axios.get('api link').then(data => {
    let live = data
    axios.get('api link2').then(data2 =>
    let current = data2
         })
    })
```

That's without diving into all of your components and lifecycle events..but might be helpful I hope.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the "best" or "correct" way to do it, but it does work. Thanks